# WSO2 EI - API context not recognized

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am developing an API in WSO2 EI 6.6 with an API context that has several parts (/context1/context2/...) I found out that it only works if I have a simple context like /context1. Otherwise when I call the API the behavior is like there was no match with the url of the API.

This work properly in ESB 4.9 and I have found this problem when building it in EI 6.6.

Here there is a sample that not work using this url http://host:port/context1/context2/template

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API1" context="/context1/context2">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/template*">
      <inSequence>
        <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

And a sample that works properly using the URL http://host:port/context1/template

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API1" context="/context1">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/template*">
      <inSequence>        
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Any help? Am I calling the API properly? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below API and it worked(http://localhost:8280/context1/context2/template2).

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API1" context="/context1/context2">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/template*">
      <inSequence>
         <loopback/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Hello" : "World"}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Maybe the behaviour of the Send mediator has changed. Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was trying to use in the context the word "odata" and it seems to be a reserved word in EI. It makes sense since dss is now inside EI, and dss can generate open data dataservices, and probably, odata it is part of the context to call these detaservices.